# Не получается записать данные в базу

Tags: php, mysqli

Ошибок ни каких нет, но и добавление почему то не происходит. Просто пишет, что "id не существует". Кто-то может подсказать как исправить?

```
if (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['id'])) {

    $userInfo = $userInfo['response'][0];
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ". $userInfo['id'] ."");
    $cols = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($cols == 0) {
        echo 'id не существует';
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO users ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'photo_50') VALUES ({$userInfo['id']}, {$userInfo['first_name']}, {$userInfo['last_name']}, {$userInfo['photo_50']})");
    } else {
        echo 'id существует';
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все необходимые данные приходят, массив не пустой.

```
array(4) {
    ["id"]=> int(122238003)
    ["first_name"]=> string(12) "Родион"
    ["last_name"]=> string(14) "Поляков"
    ["photo_50"]=> string(54) "http://cs628825.vk.me/v628825003/3f340/jHKzi1BNezk.jpg"
}
```

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO users ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'photo_50') VALUES ({$userInfo['id']}, {$userInfo['first_name']}, {$userInfo['last_name']}, {$userInfo['photo_50']})"); var_dump($result);` что выводит?

Comment: Понятно, что если не сохраняется запись, то выводится false.
Выясните, что за ошибка приходит из mysql, 
Проверьте, не дублируются ли у вас Id, не понятно, почему вы не сделали его autoincrement.
Если же дело не в этом, то `var_dump(mysqli_errno($mysqli));exit;`

Comment: @Naumov выводит false: http://ssmaker.ru/09f2b4b0.jpg

Comment: @Daniel-664 autoincrement не нужен, так как это uid от vk и он в любом случае уникальный.

Comment: Вы кавычки забыли в запросе так как текстовые данные пишите

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо фигурных скобок вокруг переменной использовать кавычку и скобку(что-то вроде `$var['one']`)